# Found maximum volume of cylinder, but can't find minimum volume?

Tags: calculus

"Find the maximum volume of a cylinder which can be placed inside a
frustrum (lampshade) whose height is 4 cms and whose radii are 1 cms and
3 cms. Is there a minimum volume for the cylinder? If so, what is the radius
of that cylinder?"

I figured out the volume function to diffrenciate in order find the maximum volume:$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(6πr^2-2πr^3)=12πr-6πr^2$$

I put that equal to zero and got 2 values for the radius, 0 and 2, plugged the 2 back into the volume function and received $8π$ which is the answer at the back of the book.

The book also says there is a minimum volume and it's radius is $3$? but I graphed the function and can see that there is a minimum but the volume would be zero and as the other radius value was at zero, I do notice that it cuts the x-axis $(r)$ at 3 on the far right...I may be missing something here as I believe the minimum value would be higher than $0\ cm^3$ unless the other minimum is at 3 but that's just cutting the x-axis right? thanks for the help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly a cylinder of radius 0 has a volume of 0.  One could argue that a radius less than 1 is not permitted, as the cylinder can expand.  This would imply that the upper surface of the cylinder must touch the slant surface of the lampshade. Even so, a cylinder of radius 3 will have a height of 0 and therefore a volume of 0, so the minimum must be 0.

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't understand how to calculate the radius of 3? I calculated a radius of 0 and 2 but not 3...please advise how to receive a radius of 3.

Comment: As Ross Millikan stated, you can assume that the cylinder must touch the lampshade. This means that $1 \le R \le 3$. Differentiation of the volume gives you one maximum, at $R=2$. But you should also check the upper and lower bounds. If you do that, you see that the upper bound $R = 3$ corresponds to the minimum value of the volume.